# Change file type associations in autohotkey script

Tags: windows-8, pdf, autohotkey, file-association

I have a Surface Pro 2 running Windows 8.1.

I use Zotero for all my academic reading, and depending on whether I'm using the surface as a laptop or as a tablet, I'd like the program used to edit PDFs to change. Specifically, I use either PDF-XChange Viewer when editing things in the desktop, and Drawboard PDF when running more of a Metro environment.

I think the simplest way to do this would be for me to write an AutoHotkey script that would toggle the file association on a particular hotkey sequence.

Any ideas how I might go about this? I imagine the file associations are probably stored in the registry, so do I just need to somehow edit the registry from an AHK script?

Comment: Assuming that Win 7 and 8 are similar regarding file type associations, here's an [explanation on how to change them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9093617/1282023). You would just have to implement this process in AHK code, I believe [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/25209-how-to-create-a-file-association-sample-script/) could be an example script. Taking your idea a step further: Provided, there is a way to detect the "surface environment", you could write a script, compile it and associate it with .pdf files. The script would then decide which program to open the file with.

Comment: Handy link. Looks like it's just a matter of editing the registry, and fortunately it appears that AHK has a [RegWrite function](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegWrite.htm).